# Long access time for static web page on virtual machine

Tags: webserver, samba, windows-networking

### My setup

1. Windows 7 on workstation that I use at work (with domain) and home (no domain)
2. Virtual machine (VMWare) that runs Arch Linux (I will call it just "Linux") with network interface in bridged mode.
3. Linux serves web pages with Nginx.
4. IP address of Linux machine is 192.168.0.16 and is added to C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts:

   192.168.0.16    bridged bri
5. IP address of Windows workstation is added to /etc/hosts:

   192.168.0.10    workstation

I can add more details to my setup description (I am not sure what is relevant).

### The question

Often (but not always) it takes long time for a web browser (Firefox) to open static web page served by Linux. I am sure it is not a performance issue.
To be more specific: it takes about ~20 seconds to resolve(?) the address `http://bridged`
 for a web browser.
Additionally I have just installed samba service and noticed similar problem, so it is not specific to browser & http. Initial access for samba shares also takes long time.

Comment: Does the performance change, if you access it by IP address rather than hostname?

Comment: @kasperd: Using raw IP in browser does not affect things, problem persists.

Comment: How does it perform, if you access it using a telnet command? If you first type `telnet 192.168.0.16 80` and then `HEAD / HTTP/1.0`, how quickly does it respond?

Comment: It may be time to give Wireshark a try. That should tell you at which point during the communication it stalls.

Comment: @kasperd: Telnet and wget fetch page immediately. As you suggested I will try Wireshark...